# Updating a column in one table through a column in another table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, sql-update, tablecolumn

I have 2 tables 'A' and 'B'. Both have a common column 'name' and linked with each other by a column 'id'. The column 'name' in the table A is empty whereas it has data in table B. My task is to fill all the data in that column from table B to table A with corresponding ids.

I'm using the following query:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.name = (SELECT B.name from B WHERE A.id = B.id)
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT B.name from B)
```

As soon as I run the query in SQL developer, it just freezes and i have to force close it. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the query?

Comment: I think that your intention is to update name by corresponding name from B, but your exists does not represent this intention - it is true for each record in A if there is at least one row in B.

Comment: You need to add `WHERE a.id = b.id` to the `WHERE EXISTS` clause, because it's really checking 'are there rows in table `b`, not 'is there a row for this id in table `b`.  And don't select a column, select a constant.  If the two id columns are in an index, but the `name` column isn't (or is in a different index), that would mean the query would only need to access the index, not the table too.

Comment: You need to add `WHERE A.id = B.id` to exists() to correlate update candidate to actual data.

Comment: @Nikola, X-Zero: Thanks guys. I see the flaw in my query. It was freezing because I had too many rows and no index. I just did the indexing and it is working fine now.

Answer (score 6):

Try this one instead:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.name = (SELECT B.name FROM B WHERE B.id = A.id AND B.name IS NOT NULL)
WHERE a.name IS NULL;
```

Since you're using Oracle, here's the reference for [IS NOT NULL](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/isnotnull.php).

Here's the SQL Fiddle so that you can play with it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a5ad0/3

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried the query but it's not working either. It can't be a problem of server right since other queries are working fine?

Comment: It was freezing because I had too many rows and no index. I just did the indexing and it is working fine now.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure from the above conversation whether you made any changes beyond indexing your data, but you should include a `WHERE EXISTS` clause as mentioned. The complete query should look like this:

```
UPDATE A
   SET A.name = ( SELECT B.name FROM B WHERE B.id = A.id )
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM B WHERE B.id = A.id )
```

The `WHERE EXISTS` clause in your original query won't do much of anything except check to see if there is at least one non-NULL value of `name` in `B`.